# Format decimal values with String in Java

Tags: java, android, format, string-formatting

I am new to android and java programming, so please forgive me if this is an easy question. My problem is to add % in end of the decimal value. I will get double value and don't know how much digits after decimal point,  i need to convert to two digits after decimal point and finally need to add % at last position. The problem is, I will format the double value only once. I have tried like this DecimalFormat ("#.##%"), but decimal points moved two digits forward. Please help me to get out of this problem.

Using DecimalFormat ("#.##%"),

Actual : 34.142545

Output : 3414.25%

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `%` in format, it means that you want to convert value to percentage, but you need to remember that value `1` in percentage world is equal to `100%` so value you use will be automatically multiplied by 100. To avoid this behaviour you can change `%` into literal by quoting it with apostrophes `'%'`

```
new DecimalFormat("#.##'%'");
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding the % in the format, you multiply by 100 and add the % character. This is why it looks like the decimal point moves.

You can use something like:

```
String output = new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(input) + "%";
```

An alternative is to divide by 100 before formatting:

```
String output = new DecimalFormat("#.##%").format(input / 100.0);
```